# Reloading page with injected javascript in Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, reload

So I created a JS script that does something on a page from the browserconsole, but when it is ready, the page needs to be reloaded in order to work properly afterwards, but if I reload the page, the JS will be deleted, because it is only injected by the browsers console.

How do I reload the page, but with my JS-Code already injected, or how do I reload the page, so that the injected JS will not be deleted?

Thanks
Hiro

Comment: Consider writing a User Script and loading it with [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/)

Comment: and tampermonkey scripts will load again if I do location.reload?

Comment: yes, they load whenever the context matches

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save some variables then you should use local or session Storage to save a variable.

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

and after refresh you can get it with

```
alert(localStorage.lastname); // Smith
```

If you want something more complex you should use Ajax and PHP.

Comment: This only allows you to persist data, not the console JavaScript. Also, ajax and PHP are unrelated.